# Pausing a non-flowing stream (delaying readable event)

Tags: node.js, stream, long-polling

On one end I have a http request (long polling). On the other end is a "game server" dispatching events. These ends are tied together with a duplex non-flowing stream in object mode and that part works fine.

The long poll end listens on `readable` and drains the stream by calling `stream.read` repeatedly. Then closes the client's connection.

The game server uses `stream.write` to push events to the clients.

Some events in the game actually spand several events and here's the problem:
When the game server adds several events at once (calling `stream.write` repeatedly) the first write triggers `readable` and the long poll is filled with the event and closed. That's very inconvinient.

The essential of the problem is that I can't silent `readable` and then trigger it when I'm done writing.
So my question is; can I somehow "pause" the stream and resume afterwards?
Is there a known another solution to this problem?

My best bet is to write an array of events, but I think that's somehow an antipattern.

Here's some code to illustrate my problem:

```
var stream = require('stream');

var connection = stream.PassThrough({ objectMode: true });

var exhaust = function() {
    console.log('exhausting');
    var chunk;
    while ((chunk = connection.read()) !== null)
        console.log(chunk);

    console.log('exhausting end');
}

connection.on('readable', function(){
    console.log('Ready to read');
    exhaust();
});

for (var i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    connection.write({ test: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an array of events to `write`, but I'm looking forward to this upcoming feature, which could be the missin solution:

http://strongloop.com/strongblog/performance-node-js-v-0-12-whats-new/
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.11.10/api/stream.html#stream_writable_cork